# How to create a static UnitOfWork for entity framework 4?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, unitofworkapplication

Considering this class

```
public class XQueries
{
    public IQueryable Query1()
    {
        using (XEntities context = new XEntities())
        {
            return something;
        }
    }

    public IQueryable Query2()
    {
        using (XEntities context = new XEntities())
        {
            return somethingElse;
        }
    }
}
```

Is a connection to the database created for every (XEntities context = new XEntities()) {...} ? If so what is the correct way to create a static UnitOfWork class so that only 1 connection to exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create a static unit of work, because by definition a unit of work is a short lived object. Because the EF `ObjectContext` is designed around the unit of work pattern it is a bad idea to have a single `ObjectContext` instance during the life time of the application. There are several reasons for this.

First of all, the `ObjectContext` class is not thread-safe. This means that during the unit of work of one user (in a web app for instance), another user can commit his unit of work. When they share the same `ObjectContext`, it means that in that situation just half of the changes are persisted and changes are not transactional. When you are lucky the `ObjectContext` fails and throws an exception. When you are unlucky, you corrupt the `ObjectContext` and safe and load crap from and to your database and find out when your application is running in production (of course, during testing and staging everything always seems to work).

Second, the `ObjectContext` has a caching mechanism that is designed for it to be short lived. When an entity is retrieved from the database it stays in the `ObjectContext`’s cache until that instance is garbage collected. When you keep that instance alive for a long period of time, entities get stale. Especially if that particular `ObjectContext` instance is not the only one writing to that database.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, so, it is ok to leave it like i posted?

Comment: Actually, you can create something like this. See this article: http://nhforge.org/wikis/patternsandpractices/nhibernate-and-the-unit-of-work-pattern.aspx (it's for NHibernate, but it can be adapted to EF as well)

Comment: It depend on your goals, but if it is about performance and correctness, your current solution is correct.

Comment: Just a clarification,  A Unit Of Work pattern is definitely not by definition a short lived object.  The major benefit of the Unit Of Work pattern (over say a normal ADO.NET transaction) is that it supports creating longer lived "business transactions" that, for example, can span multiple ASP.NET page requests.  I haven't worked with EF, but if it dictates short lived Unit Of Work transactions, it is a misleading and incorrect implementation of the pattern.

Comment: @Ash: You are correct. The scope of the Unit of Work is indeed a business transaction and business transaction and business transactions indeed don't have to be short lived. For a web application I still wouldn't advice an `ObjectContext` to outlive a web request, but this does not change the definition of the Unit of Work. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

The Entity Framework opens connections only when required, for example to execute a query or to call SaveChanges, and then closes the connection when the operation is complete.

From Martin Fowler’s book Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture in respect to Unit Of Work.

> When you're pulling data in and out of
>   a database, it's important to keep
>   track of what you've changed;
>   otherwise, that data won't be written
>   back into the database. Similarly you
>   have to insert new objects you create
>   and remove any objects you delete.
>
> You can change the database with each
>   change to your object model, but this
>   can lead to lots of very small
>   database calls, which ends up being
>   very slow. Furthermore it requires you
>   to have a transaction open for the
>   whole interaction, which is
>   impractical if you have a business
>   transaction that spans multiple
>   requests. The situation is even worse
>   if you need to keep track of the
>   objects you've read so you can avoid
>   inconsistent reads.
>
> A Unit of Work keeps track of
>   everything you do during a business
>   transaction that can affect the
>   database. When you're done, it figures
>   out everything that needs to be done
>   to alter the database as a result of
>   your work.

Whenever I use Entity Framework for a clients (which I'd admit is rare) the ObjectContext object is the Unit Of Work implementation for the system. That is the ObjectContext will somewhat meet the three statements above. Rather than concentrating too much on the absolutely correct definition using the ObjectContext makes things a little easier for you.

Do some research on DI/IoC and Repository patterns this will give you more flexibility in handling your problem.